# Live Streaming over RTMP from Wowza to iOS

Tags: ios, live, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

I'm trying to play a live stream that is being sent out by a `Wowza` server, we are using `RTMP` to handle the streams. We have an equivalent for that works on android and the way they do it is by connecting to the server via the url and 2 parameters to identify the actual stream to play and if you are allowed to see the live video. After the connection is attempted, the server does a call back sending an integer for a check to see if the user is logged in. Once the check has passed, the video is played.

I have no idea how to handle the call back or how to properly set up the connection so that it takes both parameters and the url.

One big issue is that the `Wowza` server was created by a third party that we are no longer in contact with, so i have no idea on how the actual server is set up.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Wowza has very good documentation and support on it's website.

Comment: They do and i have been able to get some connections going with some responses but the player or the webview (im trying both ways) wont play the stream

Comment: Did you try Wowza's shipped example for live stream?If that one is working the problem could be about permissons. Let us know when you solved the problem Giancarlo.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a few steps to start with:

- Determine how the Android app actually works.  Is the the server you speak of to which it sends the two parameters the Wowza server?  If so, it is probably a custom plugin.
- Get access to the server, so that you can configure it for iOS streaming.
- You'll also need to check out some documentation, http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?3-quick-start-guide, http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#cupertinostreaming

Once you have a better understanding of the problem, the Wowza folks are very helpful at http://www.wowza.com/forums.

Good luck!

Comment: can u please check this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142647/how-to-store-video-in-iphone-while-publishig-video-with-rtmpstreampublisher having some problem

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to android apps etc. Wowza is supporting the output which can be played @ ios, because of the ios cant play flash, then it cannot played rtmp or rtsp . However Ios can play the stream which is like http: // myWowzaServer/myApplication/myStream/playlist.m3u8 ...
For better config detail please visit the
http://emrekaratasoglu.com/php-freelance-watch-wowza-live-stream-apple-ios-mobile-phone/