# How to store video on iPhone while publishing video with RTMPStreamPublisher?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rtmp, avcapturesession

Right now I am using `RTMPStreamPublisher` to publish the video at wowzaserver. It's uploading there successfully, but can anyone tell me how I can store the same video on the iPhone while uploading to the server?

I am using https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos, but there is not much documentation available.  If I can just store the data that is sent for publication then my work will be successful.

Here is the method they are using to upload the stream, but I can't find a way to store the same video on my iPhone device:

```
// ACTIONS

-(void)doConnect {
#if 0 // use ffmpeg rtmp 
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", hostTextField.text, streamTextField.text];
    upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] init:url  resolution:RESOLUTION_LOW];
    upstream.delegate = self;
    upstream.encoder = [MPMediaEncoder new];
    [upstream start];
    socket = [[RTMPClient alloc] init:host]
    btnConnect.title = @"Disconnect";     
    return;
#endif

#if 0 // use inside RTMPClient instance
    upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] init:hostTextField.text resolution:RESOLUTION_LOW];
    //upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initOnlyAudio:hostTextField.text];
    //upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initOnlyVideo:hostTextField.text resolution:RESOLUTION_LOW];

#else // use outside RTMPClient instance

    if (!socket) {
        socket = [[RTMPClient alloc] init:hostTextField.text];
        if (!socket) {
            [self showAlert:@"Socket has not be created"];
            return;
        }
        [socket spawnSocketThread];
   }
    upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initWithClient:socket resolution:RESOLUTION_LOW];
#endif

    [upstream setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
    //[upstream setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    //[upstream setVideoBitrate:512000];
    upstream.delegate = self;
    [upstream stream:streamTextField.text publishType:PUBLISH_LIVE];
    //[upstream stream:streamTextField.text publishType:PUBLISH_RECORD];
    //[upstream stream:streamTextField.text publishType:PUBLISH_APPEND];
    btnConnect.title = @"Disconnect";     
}
```

I did find that with the instance of `BroadcastStreamClient` named as "upstream" I can get the `AVCaptureSession` via the following line

```
[upstream getCaptureSession];
```

How can I use this `AVCaptureSession` for recording the video on the iPhone?

Comment: To store the device as a file on your iOS device I'm guessing you would need specific code to do that.  Wowza is a streaming server so you would not use that to download the file.  I can't provide an answer as I'm not familiar with iOS.

Comment: thanx for the answer..but the code i have given in snippet is not of wowza.. i juset found that library from Github and that just working with rtmp.

Comment: Hi Bhavik Kama, Can you give the sample code for streaming iOS video to wowza using MedialIb. I am trying the sample, but I am able to see only the connection being established with wowza from my ios program, couldn't understand how to stream video to wowza further.

Comment: you can find the sample code here https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos/tree/master/RTMPStreamPlayer

Comment: Hi Bhavik Kama, Unfortunately this is not streaming video to wowza, but it is able to make the connection. I am running RTMPStreamPublisher successfully on my iOS device. Now, I am able to click on Connect it to connect with Wowza successfully. Fine. Next, the options like toggle camera and start buttons are still greyed out. So, I enabled these buttons in MainStoryBoard and run this application. After the successful connection, if I click on “Start” button, not sure what is happening in the behind, whether it streams live recorded video to Wowza or not,

Comment: because I am not seeing this opening camera and recording live or anything like that. And also, I am not seeing streamed video is being received in Wowza streaming engine as well.

Comment: actually i have worked on this thing very long before. so i will give u feedback as i find somthng usefull to you

Comment: need to find it out the sources and the links i have used for so if u can wait for that

Comment: I can wait, pls give your sample, which would help a lot.

Comment: hi @Daisy can u please check this link http://www.wowza.com/pricing/trial you need to download the sample code and then it will provide you the downloaded and streaming content here please check the guide they have given please check this link too http://www.wowza.com/pricing/installer

Comment: HI Bhavik Kama, I have already Wowza setup in my machine. I want to have some iOS sample project to stream live video from iOS device to connect with Wowza and stream video

Comment: hi better you message me at ma account or create chat session will explain u wht u have to do

Comment: Just purely FTR, if you are dealing only with **short** videos (I think the limit is 90 seconds), just use parse.com - it's unbelievably easy, not to mention free etc

Answer (score 1):

Once you got the `AVCaptureSession` you can add to it an instance of `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` like this:

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput new];
if([captureSession canAddOutput:movieFileOutput]){
    [captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];
}

// Start recording
NSURL *outputURL = …
[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

Source: 
https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/

Also take a look at this in order to better understand how to use an `AVCaptureFileOutput`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureFileOutput

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you selected video from photo album or recorded. or in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method

```
NSURL __block *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
             UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly cache the video with NSKeyedArchiver as long as your object conforms `<NSCoding>` protocol (many collection types already conform to this). This cache directory gets periodically cleaned out

http://khanlou.com/2015/07/cache-me-if-you-can/

Or maybe a better alternative may be to use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` to store your temporary video file (this is part of `NSPathUtilities`) locally. AVAssetExportSession should allow you to put the video file there:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = outputFileURL;
```